# Как получить доступ к тому, что написано через терминал, python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xubuntu

Я учу питон, и мне хотелось бы получить историю к тому, что было написано в терминале (интерактивный режим). Иногда тестирую разное и чтобы не перепечатывать это в `*.py` файл хотелось бы копировать уже написанное.

Ну, в смысле, сам интерпретатор же как-то получает историю, значит и я могу, по идее, так ведь?

У меня `Xubuntu`. Ну та же `Ubuntu`, но с оболочкой `xfce`.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: а сочетание клавиш таб + стрела вверх,вниз не катит?

Comment: Можно ещё [jupyter notebook попробовать](https://try.jupyter.org/) в качестве REPL.

Answer (score 1):

История интерактивного режима должна быть расположена в домашней папке в скрытом файле `.python_history`

То есть чтобы получить историю вам достаточно открыть файл с помощью какого-либо текстового редактора.

Попробуйте:

```
mousepad ~/.python_history
```

Answer (score 0):

> Иногда тестирую разное и чтобы не перепечатывать это в *.py файл хотелось бы копировать уже написанное.

Для таких случаев (опробовать функционал Python или каких-то библиотек) удобно использовать [**jupyter notebook**](http://jupyter.org/). По сути это та же консоль python, только в веб-интерфейсе. Особенности:

- Ввод считается "ячейкой", к которой прикреплен вывод
- Каждую ячейку можно при необходимости перезапускать
- Ячейки можно удалять/передвигать, добавлять новые выше/ниже данной
- Выводом ячейки может быть не только текст, но и, например, изображение, или график, выводимый библиотекой matplotlib, или таблица pandas
- Ячейки могут содержать не только код, но и например пояснения в формате markdown. В этом случае нужно поменять тип ячейки на markdown.
- Все содержимое сохраняется в файл с расширением ipynb, который можно повторно открыть и с ним работать
- Можно экспортировать содержимое в различные форматы (py, html, markdown, reST, pdf)

Как все это может выглядеть (скриншот относительно старой версии, когда `jupyter notebook` еще назывался `ipython notebook`):

[image: изображение]

Я использую jupyter для подготовки ответов для ru.stackoverflow.com:

[image: изображение 2]

Чтобы установить, нужно выполнить `pip install jupyter` в консоли, запуск - `jupyter notebook`.